# SFML/OpenGL.hpp missing on linux

Tags: linux, opengl, sfml

Im trying to port my sfml opengl game to linux but I ran into some problems. I managed to get a small opengl program to run as well as a sfml program but for some reason i cant get sfml openGL programs to compile. Turns out im missing the SFML/OpenGL.hpp header file but I cant figure out why. So my question is, what package do i need to install to get this file?

oh by the way. Im using Ubuntu and these are some of the packages i have installed so far if that helps.

```
2013-12-07 02:08:11 install libwxbase2.8-0 <none> 2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2
2013-12-07 02:08:12 install libwxgtk2.8-0 <none> 2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2
2013-12-07 02:08:15 install libcodeblocks0 <none> 10.05-2
2013-12-07 02:08:17 install codeblocks-common <none> 10.05-2
2013-12-07 02:08:20 install codeblocks <none> 10.05-2
2013-12-07 02:29:15 install libstdc++6-4.6-dev <ingen> 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
2013-12-07 02:29:19 install g++-4.6 <ingen> 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
2013-12-07 02:29:25 install g++ <ingen> 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
2013-12-07 02:29:26 install libtimedate-perl <ingen> 1.2000-1
2013-12-07 02:29:27 install libdpkg-perl <ingen> 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.2
2013-12-07 02:29:28 install dpkg-dev <ingen> 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.2
2013-12-07 02:29:30 install build-essential <ingen> 11.5ubuntu2.1
2013-12-07 02:29:31 install fakeroot <ingen> 1.18.2-1
2013-12-07 02:29:32 install libalgorithm-diff-perl <ingen> 1.19.02-2
2013-12-07 02:29:33 install libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl <ingen> 0.04-2build2
2013-12-07 02:29:34 install libalgorithm-merge-perl <ingen> 0.08-2
2013-12-07 14:41:52 install libkms1 <ingen> 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.3
2013-12-07 14:41:53 install libdrm-dev <ingen> 2.4.43-0ubuntu0.0.3
2013-12-07 14:41:55 install libpthread-stubs0 <ingen> 0.3-3
2013-12-07 14:41:56 install libpthread-stubs0-dev <ingen> 0.3-3
2013-12-07 14:41:57 install xorg-sgml-doctools <ingen> 1:1.10-1
2013-12-07 14:41:57 install x11proto-core-dev <ingen> 7.0.22-1ubuntu0.1
2013-12-07 14:41:59 install libxau-dev <ingen> 1:1.0.6-4
2013-12-07 14:42:00 install libxdmcp-dev <ingen> 1:1.1.0-4
2013-12-07 14:42:01 install x11proto-input-dev <ingen> 2.1.99.6-1
2013-12-07 14:42:02 install x11proto-kb-dev <ingen> 1.0.5-2
2013-12-07 14:42:03 install xtrans-dev <ingen> 1.2.6-2
2013-12-07 14:42:04 install libxcb1-dev <ingen> 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2
2013-12-07 14:42:05 install libx11-dev <ingen> 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2
2013-12-07 14:42:06 install libx11-doc <ingen> 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2
2013-12-07 14:42:11 install mesa-common-dev <ingen> 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6
2013-12-07 14:51:58 install libpcrecpp0 <ingen> 8.12-4
2013-12-07 14:51:58 install libsdl-image1.2 <ingen> 1.2.10-3
2013-12-07 14:51:59 install libtiffxx0c2 <ingen> 3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5
2013-12-07 14:52:00 install libasound2-dev <ingen> 1.0.25-1ubuntu10.2
2013-12-07 14:52:01 install libavahi-common-dev <ingen> 0.6.30-5ubuntu2
2013-12-07 14:52:02 install libdbus-1-dev <ingen> 1.4.18-1ubuntu1.4
2013-12-07 14:52:03 install libavahi-client-dev <ingen> 0.6.30-5ubuntu2
2013-12-07 14:52:04 install libtinfo-dev <ingen> 5.9-4
2013-12-07 14:52:05 install libncurses5-dev <ingen> 5.9-4
2013-12-07 14:52:06 install zlib1g-dev <ingen> 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4
2013-12-07 14:52:07 install libpng12-dev <ingen> 1.2.46-3ubuntu4
2013-12-07 14:52:08 install libslang2-dev <ingen> 2.2.4-3ubuntu1
2013-12-07 14:52:09 install libcaca-dev <ingen> 0.99.beta17-2.1ubuntu2
2013-12-07 14:52:11 install libpcre3-dev <ingen> 8.12-4
2013-12-07 14:52:13 install libglib2.0-dev <ingen> 2.32.4-0ubuntu1
2013-12-07 14:52:16 install x11proto-xext-dev <ingen> 7.2.0-3
2013-12-07 14:52:17 install libxext-dev <ingen> 2:1.3.0-3ubuntu0.1
2013-12-07 14:52:18 install libgl1-mesa-dev <ingen> 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6
2013-12-07 14:52:19 install libglu1-mesa-dev <ingen> 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.6
2013-12-07 14:52:20 install libice-dev <ingen> 2:1.0.7-2build1
2013-12-07 14:52:23 install libjpeg-turbo8-dev <ingen> 1.1.90+svn733-0ubuntu4.1
2013-12-07 14:52:24 install libjpeg8-dev <ingen> 8c-2ubuntu7
2013-12-07 14:52:25 install libjpeg-dev <ingen> 8c-2ubuntu7
2013-12-07 14:52:26 install libpulse-dev <ingen> 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4
2013-12-07 14:52:27 install libsm-dev <ingen> 2:1.2.0-2build1
2013-12-07 14:52:28 install libxt-dev <ingen> 1:1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1
2013-12-07 14:52:29 install libsdl1.2-dev <ingen> 1.2.14-6.4ubuntu3
2013-12-07 14:52:32 install libtiff4-dev <ingen> 3.9.5-2ubuntu1.5
2013-12-07 14:52:33 install libsdl-image1.2-dev <ingen> 1.2.10-3
2013-12-12 20:55:48 install libopenal-data <ingen> 1:1.13-4ubuntu3
2013-12-12 20:55:49 install libopenal1 <ingen> 1:1.13-4ubuntu3
2013-12-12 20:55:50 install libglew1.5 <ingen> 1.5.7.is.1.5.2-1ubuntu4
2013-12-12 20:55:51 install libsfml-system1.6 <ingen> 1.6+dfsg1-2ubuntu2
2013-12-12 20:55:51 install libsfml-audio1.6 <ingen> 1.6+dfsg1-2ubuntu2
2013-12-12 20:55:52 install libsfml-window1.6 <ingen> 1.6+dfsg1-2ubuntu2
2013-12-12 20:55:53 install libsoil1 <ingen> 1.07~20080707.dfsg-2
2013-12-12 20:55:54 install libsfml-graphics1.6 <ingen> 1.6+dfsg1-2ubuntu2
2013-12-12 20:55:55 install libsfml-network1.6 <ingen> 1.6+dfsg1-2ubuntu2
2013-12-12 20:55:56 install libsfml-dev <ingen> 1.6+dfsg1-2ubuntu2
2013-12-13 21:55:41 install libopenal-dev <ingen> 1:1.13-4ubuntu3
2013-12-13 22:05:57 install x11proto-randr-dev <ingen> 1.4.0+git20120101.is.really.1.4.0-0ubuntu1~precise2
2013-12-13 22:05:58 install x11proto-render-dev <ingen> 2:0.11.1-2
2013-12-13 22:05:58 install libxrender-dev <ingen> 1:0.9.6-2ubuntu0.1
2013-12-13 22:06:00 install libxrandr-dev <ingen> 2:1.3.2-2ubuntu0.2
2013-12-13 22:07:07 install libfreetype6-dev <ingen> 2.4.8-1ubuntu2.1
2013-12-13 22:07:52 install libglew1.5-dev <ingen> 1.5.7.is.1.5.2-1ubuntu4
2013-12-13 22:08:59 install libogg-dev <ingen> 1.2.2~dfsg-1ubuntu1
2013-12-13 22:09:01 install libflac-dev <ingen> 1.2.1-6
2013-12-13 22:09:01 install libvorbis-dev <ingen> 1.3.2-1ubuntu3
2013-12-13 22:09:03 install libsndfile1-dev <ingen> 1.0.25-4
```

Comment: What distro are you using? Where did you get the "rest" of SFML? You can always build from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out the linux package only installs an old version of sfml (for some reason). So i did what Lukas suggested and built it from source instead. Now it works fine.
I followed this tutorial to build the library.
http://sfmlcoder.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/building-sfml-2-0-with-make-for-gcc/